# Filtering even columns in SAS

Tags: python, sas

I have a data set with financial data that has a particular structure:

```
|Date    |price1  |Date    |price2  |...|Date    |priceN  |
|dd/mm/yy|numeric |dd/mm/yy|numeric |...|dd/mm/yy|numeric |
|dd/mm/yy|numeric |dd/mm/yy|numeric |...|dd/mm/yy|numeric |
|dd/mm/yy|numeric |dd/mm/yy|numeric |...|dd/mm/yy|numeric |
```

I need pivot the data from wide to long, but first I have to select only first column (Date) and the all the price columns, i.e., all the even columns. I did it in python and it worked so used chat gpt to translate it to SAS, but it didn't work, chat gpt give the following code:

```
data filter_price;
set price;
array columns[*] _all_;
do i=1 to dim(columns);
   if mod(i,2)=0 then output;
end;
keep columns:;
run;
```

The result of the code above is a data set like this:

```
|Date    |price1  |Date    |price2  |...|Date    |priceN  |i  |  
|dd/mm/yy|numeric |dd/mm/yy|numeric |...|dd/mm/yy|numeric |2  |
|dd/mm/yy|numeric |dd/mm/yy|numeric |...|dd/mm/yy|numeric |4  |
|dd/mm/yy|numeric |dd/mm/yy|numeric |...|dd/mm/yy|numeric |6  |
```

It adds a column with something like an index that take only even numbers. What I need as a result is the following:

```
|Date    |price1  |price2  |...|priceN  |
|dd/mm/yy|numeric |numeric |...|numeric |
|dd/mm/yy|numeric |numeric |...|numeric |
|dd/mm/yy|numeric |numeric |...|numeric |
```

Can you help me with this? I leave you what I made in python in case it were useful.

```
import pandas as pd
# Lee el archivo de precios
df = pd.read_excel("/content/prueba_pivote_precios.xlsm")

# Elimina la primera fila (que no tiene datos)
df.drop(0, axis=0, inplace=True)

# identifica el nombre de las columnas (el nombre válido de las columnas viene cada dos columnas)
names = df.columns.to_list()
names2 = []
for i in range(len(names)):
  if i%2!=0:
    names2.append(names[i])

# Selecciona las columnas válidas
df2 = df[names2]

# recupera la columna de fechas del data set original
df3["FECHA"] = df.iloc[:, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have columns with the same names in SAS.

However, you can easily select all columns with the name price using the following statements.

```
data want;
set have;

KEEP DATE PRICE:;
run;
```

or if there's a sequence of variables you want to keep:

```
data want;
set have; 

KEEP DATE PRICE1-PRICEN;
run;
```

If you're looking to keep only price2, price4, that's a different ask.

Looking for 'even' columns is the wrong approach in SAS.

EDIT: Here's another way. If you do have a pattern in your middle variable (ie it is date, there are ways to drop that rather than keep all)

```
*get the list of variable names;
proc sql noprint;
select name into :var_list separated by " "
from sashelp.vcolumns 
where libname='WORK' and memname='WANT'
and varnum =1 or mod(varnum, 2)=0;
quit;

%put &var_list;

data want;
set have;
keep &var_list.;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems to be ok if the names of the variables have something like a keyword (PRICE in this case) the problem (and I apologize for not specifying it) is that the name for each variable is different because it takes the ticker of each company, for example, JPMN, TSLA, MSFT, etc. that's the reason I thought in take only even columns and not selecting by name.

Comment: I still don't get what EVEN has to do with the problem.  It you to select VARIABLES named JMN and MSFT then just do that.

Answer (score 0):

If by "pivot" you mean TRANSPOSE then just use an ARRAY.  I am assuming that all of the variables are NUMERIC.

```
data want;
 set have;
 array prices _numeric_;
 length name $32 price 8;
 do index=2 to dim(prices) by 2;
   name=vname(prices[index]);
   price=prices[index];
   output;
 end;
 keep date name price;
run;
```

So not only will it skip over the DATE variables it will also convert your impossible to use WIDE structure into a TALL structure which will be much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

A data set of just dates and prices would indicate to me that the data set name plays a data role of identifying the associated commodity.

An consistent rectangular **across** data structure would have columns named `price1` through `priceN` and `date1` through `dateN` where each row is for a week or month, and at the far right there will be cases of missing values due to some rows covering a shorter date domain than others.

Your panda code indicates the names of the columns are irrelevant, and columns are presumed to be consistently adjacent pairs of `date` and `price`.

Consistently named pairs of columns can be transposed pairwise in one pass by using arrays.

```
proc import datafile='.../whatever.xlsm' out=have ;

data want (keep=commodity date price);
  commodity = 'whatever' ;
  set have ;
  array dates date: ;
  array prices price: ;
  do over dates ;                         /* WIDE */
    if missing(dates) then continue ;
    date = dates ;
    price = prices ;
    OUTPUT ;                              /* to TALL */
  end ;
  format date ddmmyy8. ;
run ;
```

For the case of inconsistent names, but presumptively consistent pairs with each pair being correctly imported as numeric. *Stray values in an Excel column can turn a human presumed column of numbers into a column of character values when imported*

Example:

The do loop starts at 2 and addresses date by index-1 in order to protect against addressing beyond the array. If the loop started at 1 and addressed price at index+1 you could go beyond the array when your data has an odd number of columns (due to data-issues in the .xlsm)

```
data want (keep=commodity date price) ;
  commodity = 'whatever' ;
  set have ;
  array numbers _numeric_ ;
  do index = 2 to dim(numbers) BY 2; * pairwise advancement ;
    date = numbers[index-1] ;
    if missing (date) then continue ;
    price = numbers[index] ;
    OUTPUT ;
  end ;
end ;
```